# Display corresponding key binding of command during M-x completion

Tags: key-bindings, commands, ivy

As an example, when I use `M-x save-buffer` Emacs says in the minibuffer:

```
 You can run the command ‘save-buffer’ with C-x C-s
```

I'm using [Swiper/Ivy](http://oremacs.com/swiper/); I want to know if there is a way to instruct Ivy to append the keybinding of a command while it shows the completion options; something like `save-buffer (C-x C-s)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command `counsel-M-x` does this for you:

[image: Screenshot of <code>counsel-M-x</code> in action]

[`(ivy) Global key bindings`](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#global-key-bindings) recommends you remap <kbd>M-x</kbd> (`execute-extended-command`) to `counsel-M-x` in order to avail of its [increased Ivy-ness](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#counsel-commands), e.g. via

```el
(when (commandp 'counsel-M-x)
  (global-set-key [remap execute-extended-command] #'counsel-M-x))
```

Alternatively (and more simply), you can just enable `counsel-mode` and have it automatically remap various built-in commands, including `describe-function` and `describe-variable`, to their fancier `counsel` counterparts.

#### Update

In fact, vanilla Emacs 28 has this functionality too:

[image: Emacs 28 M-x screenshot]